# Sidebar with sticky footer and dynamic content

Tags: html, css, layout

I got this layout from another stackoverflow-question (jsfiddle link is at the end), and it works (the footer sticks to the bottom and moves down when the content gets larger):
[working sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfh7d.png)

But there is one huge problem:
My sidebar will not have a fixed size and will mostly be higher than the whole page. But if I add content to the sidebar the fiddle doesn't work anymore:
[buggy sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWWfC.png)

What can I do to fix this problem? Would be very nice if you add the working JSFiddle to your answer.

Thank you in advance.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZhpH/41/), Snippet below:

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto -50px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
 position: relative
}
#footer {
 height: 50px;
}
#footer-content {
 border: 1px solid magenta;
 height: 32px; /* height + top/bottom paddding + top/bottom border must add up to footer height */
 padding: 8px;
}
.push {
 height: 50px;
 clear: both;
}

#header {
 height: 50px;
}
#header-content {
 border: 1px solid magenta;
 height: 32px; /* height + top/bottom paddding + top/bottom border must add up to footer height */
 padding: 8px;
}
#content {
 height: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
 border: 1px solid skyblue;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 50px;
 bottom: 50px;
}
#main {
 margin-left: 102px
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header"><div id="header-content">Header</div></div>
 <div id="content">
  <div id="sidebar">Sidebar<br/>Sidebar<br/>Sidebar<br/>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
   Main<br />
   Main<br />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"><div id="footer-content">Footer</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will solve your problem. My code base on `table display` and `100vh height` with `calc` that less the header and footer height.

**Now you have a dynamic sidebar:**

```css
html, body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
min-height: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
height: auto !important;
}

#footer {
z-index: 1;
height: 50px;
}

#footer-content {
background: magenta;
height: 32px; /* height + top/bottom paddding + top/bottom border must add up to footer height */
padding: 8px;
}

#header {
height: 48px;
}

#header-content {
background: magenta;
height: 32px; /* height + top/bottom paddding + top/bottom border must add up to footer height */
padding: 8px;
}

#content {
display: table;
width: 100%;
min-height: calc(100vh - 98px);
}

#sidebar {
z-index: -1;
display: table-cell;
background: skyblue;
width: 100px;
}

#main {
display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"><div id="header-content">Header</div></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="sidebar">
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
      Sidebar<br/>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        Main<br />
        Main<br />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer"><div id="footer-content">Footer</div></div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZhpH/1549/)**

Comment: Doesn't fully work:

Theres a point where it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/UhTMeGC.png

Comment: And when the sidebar-content is not enough it looks wrong as well: http://i.imgur.com/FT3U63k.png

Comment: Which browser you using?

Comment: Now it doesn't stick the footer to the bottom

Comment: what? its not make sense. add an image please.

Comment: There is this space: http://i.imgur.com/2RMltuo.png The footer doesn't stick to the bottom

Comment: Did you update your code? For me it isnt working (on jsfiddle)

Comment: try to use chrome. i need to know where the problem come from.